# Calling same function in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a function that does the ajax GET request and it returns the success or error response. In success response, I am again calling the same function but after 2 sec. For this, I have following code.

```
function check_something()
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/something',
    success: function(data){
      setTimeout(check_something(),2000);
    },
    error: function(response) {
      if(response.status == 401){
        //do something else
      }
    }
  });
};


$(function(){
   check_something();
});
```

But from network console log and server log it looks like a request for "/something" are coming at faster than 2 sec interval. I see that request are incoming after like 10 or 12 ms.

What can be the problem with piece of code?

Comment: **DO NOT** call the function..Just pass the handler to setTimeOut

Answer (score 6):

You're calling the function and passing the result as the first argument to `setTimeout`, instead of passing a reference to the function. The correct syntax would be:

```
setTimeout(check_something, 2000);
```

Comment: ahh. Stupid me. Didn't noticed it. Thanks.